# Div container won't center using CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css

Just trying to figure out why this `div` won't center. If I can get this working, I'll be set.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/391sz22s/)

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:60%;
    text-align:center;  
}

ul li{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    float:left; 
}

ul li a{
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:Bold;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Arial;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#7A991A;
}

#container{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Every time I try to display it in the browser, it looks like this:

[image]

Also how do I stretch the navigation bar to 100%? Like from the very left of the page to the right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to center a `div` without specified width. For that, first remove `ul{width:60%;}`, then add `text-align:center` to the Parent and `display:inline-block` to the Child :

```
#container{
    text-align:center;  
}
ul{
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 
ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block; 
}

ul li{
 text-transform:uppercase;
 float:left; 
}

ul li a{
 display: block;
 width: 120px;
 text-decoration:none;
 background-color:#98bf21;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0px;
 padding:10px;
 font-weight:Bold;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:Arial;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul li a:hover{
 background-color:#7A991A; 
}

#container{
 width:100%;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

```html
<body> 
  <div id = "container">
    <ul>
   <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">News</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that the links will wrap onto a second line as the screen size shrinks.

Answer (score 2):

1、delete margin: 0 auto;width:60%;from ul and add display: table;margin: 0 auto;like this：

```
ul{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    /* margin: 0 auto;
    width:60%; */
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

2、delete margin: 0 auto;width:60%;from ul and add ‘text-align: center’ in #container，‘display: inline-block’ in ul like this:

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

3、

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
ul{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

4、

```
 #container{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
} 
ul{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
}
```

5、

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
}
ul{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

may help you。
choose the best one for you project。

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

Set `display: table` to the `ul` element, which will give you a shrink-to-fit block level element that will then center using `margin: 0 auto`.

Set `display: table-cell` on the `li` elements.

The advantage of this approach is that the links will remain on a single line no matter how small you make the page width, which may be the desired effect for some designs.

You could set the with of the `ul` to 100%, but then your link elements would increase in width, which may not be what you want.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    display: table;
}
ul li {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display: table-cell;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:Bold;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Arial;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
#container {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

All I did was moving the background color to the #container, removed the 60% width, and make the LI elements display: inline-block

```
ul li{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/391sz22s/1/

Comment: Someone literally answered a abit ago.  Thanks though.. That is close but it was only ul{}

Comment: Hahah no worries :) Good luck!